# Symfony 3 Login form infinity loop

Tags: php, symfony-forms, symfony

My Symfony version is: 3.0.6

I'm fighting from few hours with authentication.
I have form with login & password.

My security.yml looks:

```
security:

encoders:
    MainListBundle\Entity\User:
        algorithm: bcrypt

providers:
    default:
        entity:
            class: MainListBundle:User
            property: username

firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    my_app:
        pattern:   ^/
        anonymous: ~
        form_login:
            login_path: /login
            check_path: /login_check
            default_target_path: main_list_homepage
        logout:
            path: /logout
            target: main_list_login
```

Form can show me if username does not exist in database.
But If I put some password (wrong as well) I have infinite loop on "check_path" URL.

Fields on login form are correct: _username and _password.
Form "action" is the same as "check_path" in security.

What I made wrong...
It is very weird because all is like on the tutorials.

Controller:

```
<?php

namespace MainListBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;

class LoginController extends Controller
{

    public function indexAction(Request $Request)
    {
        $auth = $this->get('security.authentication_utils');
        $error = $auth->getLastAuthenticationError();
        $username = $auth->getLastUserName();

        return $this->render('MainListBundle:Login:login.html.twig', array(
            'loginError' => $error,
            'username' => $username
        ));
    }
```

Routing.yml

```
main_list_sort:
    path:     /MainList/sort/{field}
    defaults: { _controller: MainListBundle:Default:sort }

main_list_search:
    path:     /MainList/search
    defaults: { _controller: MainListBundle:Default:search }

main_list_clear_search:
    path:     /MainList/clearSearch
    defaults: { _controller: MainListBundle:Default:clearSearch }

main_list_pdfGenerateRecordsList:
    path:     /MainList/pdfGenerateRecordsList
    defaults: { _controller: MainListBundle:Default:pdfGenerateRecordsList }

main_list_homepage:
    path:     /MainList/{page}
    defaults: { _controller: MainListBundle:Default:index, page: 1 }

main_list_login:
    path:     /login
    defaults: { _controller: MainListBundle:Login:index }

main_list_login_check:
    path:     /login_check

main_list_logout:
    path:     /logout
    defaults: { _controller: MainListBundle:Login:logout }

main_list_add_users:
    path:     /addusers
    defaults: { _controller: MainListBundle:Login:addUsers }
```

Form view:

```
{% extends "::base.html.twig" %}

{% block menu %}{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

    <center>
        {% if loginError is defined and loginError is not null %}
            <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ loginError.messageKey }}</div>
        {% endif %}

        <form action="{{ path('main_list_login_check') }}" method="POST">
            <table style="width: 600px">
                <tr>
                    <td>Login:</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="_username" value="{{ username }}"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Password:</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="password" name="_password" value=""/>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="submit" value="Zaloguj"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </center>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Just for kicks, change your Login/Logout paths to login/logout.  Doubt if it will help but maybe there is a case sensitivity issue.  And it looks weird.

Comment: Can you show template of the login form and routes definitions?

Comment: @MichałSznurawa  - I've edited post. Routing and form view have been added

Comment: try to change to `check_path: /login_check` and then try to change `default_target_path: main_list_login` not to login page, you are redirecting to login page again after login

Comment: @DenisAlimov - Still the same problem :(

Comment: you have `access_control:
    - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }` in security.yml right? does your logined user has ADMIN role?

Comment: @DenisAlimov - I see some progress. In database I had ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN instead of ROLE_ADMIN. Now I don't have infinite loop but I have message: "Authentication request could not be processed due to a system problem."  :O

Comment: this error usually caused by mismatch between database table and User entity

Comment: @DenisAlimov - Ughh.. I was thinking that problem with loop was solved.. I had small problem with unserialize function in model. I've fixed it and infinite loop was back again :/  (I need go for beer to fridge... go mad)

Comment: Still does not work ... Can anyone help me ? :(

Answer (score 1):

As [Symphony documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html#be-sure-the-login-page-isn-t-secure-redirect-loop) says:

> 2. Be Sure the Login Page Isn't Secure (Redirect Loop!)

you should add next rule to your `access_control`:

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

And don't forget to add `anonymous: ~` before `form_login` and `access_control` in your `security.yml`.

Look docs for more info.

BR